# how to find the length of the string on the array?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, strlen

I'm trying to get the length of the string from a char array

My input is:`alpha kian namikian` and the output should be `5 4 8` but at the moment my output is `11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11` which is not what I'm trying to achieve.

```
int i,count;
char str[100];  
cout<<"enter string\n";
for(i=0;;i++)
{
    cin>>str[i];

    if(cin.get()=='\n')
    {
        count=i+1;
        break;
    }
}
for(i=0;i<count;i++)
{
    int len = strlen(str);
    cout<<len<<"\n";
}
```

Comment: Try to use char instead of string in array.

Comment: okay ill try to change

Comment: For example: “string” is an array of chars.

Comment: okay so i adjusted it but the result
ouput is not correct 


when i tried this

input: alpha kian namikian
output: 
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a compilation error because you're trying to fit an array of strings as a parameter to `strlen`. In your code, `str` contains all the strings, so you have to use access operator `[]` just like you did when you were taking strings from standard input.

`int len = strlen(str)` becomes `int len = strlen(str[i])` and that should fix the error.

EDIT:

It looks like you can't use `strlen` with strings. Use `length()` instead.

`int len = str[i].length()`

EDIT #2:

Adding full code for reference with output:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i, count;
    string str[100];
    cout << "enter string\n";
    for (i = 0;; i++)
    {
        cin >> str[i];

        if (cin.get() == '\n')
        {
            count = i + 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        int len = str[i].length();
        cout << len << "\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

> enter string
>
> alpha kian namikian
>
> 5
>
> 4
>
> 8

Comment: so i tried to change it
but the result is [Error] invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]

Comment: int i,count,len;
 char str[100]; 
 cout<<"enter string\n";
 
 for(i=0;;i++)
 {
  cin>>str[i];
  
 
  if(cin.get()=='\n')
  {
   count=i+1;
   break;
  }
 }
 
 
 
 
 for(i=0;i<count;i++)
 {
  len = strlen(str[i]);
  cout<<len<<"\n";
    }

Comment: im sorry i dont know how to proper line of this code same as my post
im new im sorry

Comment: Look at my edit, you actually can't use `strlen()` with strings - you have to use `length()`

Comment: May by “sizeof str/ sizeof str[i]” give you length without loop

Comment: oh okay
i get it now

bro thank you so much
i appreciate this hahaha

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach using the `vector` type `string` and exit the storing of the strings if entered string is `exit` 

I am using a `temp` variable to store the string at any index and output the corresponding length.

```
    int i;
    vector<string> str;
    cout << "Enter String\n";
    while(cin)
    {
        string temp;
        cin >> temp;
        if(temp == "exit")
            break;
        else
            str.push_back(temp);

    }
    int n= str.size();
    for(i = 0; i< n; i++)
    {
        string temp = str[i];
        int len = temp.length();
        cout << len << endl;
    }
```